# Php session vars not showing in print/print preview. Printing from gpad 7 tablet using chrome browser

Tags: php, android, session, printing

For  some reason, session variables are not showing when I print from my tablet. If I print the same screen from my PC, the data shows just fine. Local vars show fine in both scenarios.

Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Tablet: LG Gpad 7 4G/wifi
Browser: Latest ver.of chrome for android
Print method: Printershare app over wifi
Website: Hosted in server2003 server

Session vars definitely hold the correct value and session_start(); is at the top of the page.

```
<?php
session_start();

$nonlocal = $_SESSION['hasdata'];
$local = "this shows in print preview";

echo $local;
echo $nonlocal;
```

Comment: It seems that my session id is changing when print preview starts. How can I pass the session id to the print preview page?

Comment: I got around the problem by storing the temp values in a text file instead of in the session, but i'd really like to know what causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Include favicon in headers. I feel like a moron.